# How to sort a list in Python based on a set of keys in different levels

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a `list` of dictionaries in `python`. I want to sort it by `key`s i.e., first by `chain_id`, then by `start.residue_number` and then by `end.residue_number`. In the `list` below, the 4th and 6th element should be coming the other way around. I could use `sorted` with `from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter` to sort on `chain_id`, but how to do same with a `dictionary` inside `dictionary`?

```
            "mappings": [
                {
                    "entity_id": 1,
                    "end": {
                        "residue_number": 63
                    },
                    "start": {
                        "residue_number": 1
                    },
                    "chain_id": "A",
                    "struct_asym_id": "A"
                },
                {
                    "entity_id": 1,
                    "end": {
                        "residue_number": 116
                    },
                    "start": {
                        "residue_number": 1
                    },
                    "chain_id": "A",
                    "struct_asym_id": "A"
                },
                {
                    "entity_id": 1,
                    "end": {
                        "residue_number": 124
                    },
                    "start": {
                        "residue_number": 1
                    },
                    "chain_id": "A",
                    "struct_asym_id": "A"
                },
                {
                    "entity_id": 1,
                    "end": {
                        "residue_number": 116
                    },
                    "start": {
                        "residue_number": 1
                    },
                    "chain_id": "B",
                    "struct_asym_id": "B"
                },
                {
                    "entity_id": 1,
                    "end": {
                        "residue_number": 124
                    },
                    "start": {
                        "residue_number": 1
                    },
                    "chain_id": "B",
                    "struct_asym_id": "B"
                },
                {
                    "entity_id": 1,
                    "end": {
                        "residue_number": 63
                    },
                    "start": {
                        "residue_number": 1
                    },
                    "chain_id": "B",
                    "struct_asym_id": "B"
                }
            ]
```

Comment: That's `SyntaxError` rather than a list of dictionaries. Can you provide a **[mcve]** and show us what you have tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed `d` as your dict, Solved with `sorted` and `lambda`

```
# Sort with chain_id
In [93]: sort_1 = sorted(d['mappings'],key=lambda x:x['chain_id'])
# Sort with start residue number
In [94]: sort_2 = sorted(sort_1,key=lambda x:x['start']['residue_number'])
# Sort with end residue number
In [95]: sort_3 = sorted(sort_2,key=lambda x:x['end']['residue_number'])
```

Or you can do in a line.

```
sorted(d['mappings'],key=lambda x:(x['chain_id'],x['start']['residue_number'],x['end']['residue_number']))
```

Inspired from leotrubach's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the keys are to be sorted in descending order you could use [`list.sort()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.list.sort) or [`sorted()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/builtins.sorted) functions and create a tuple returning key function:

```
print(
    sorted(
        mappings, 
        key=lambda x: (
            x['chain_id'], 
            x['start']['residue_number'], 
            x['end']['residue_number']
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: This really helps. Thanks